# MongoDB aggregation $let expression to Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java

I have following $let expression :

```
{
"$let": {
    "vars": {
        "h": {
            "$hour": "$Date"
        }
    },
    "in": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$lt": [
                    "$$h",
                    6
                ]
            },
            "then": "Night",
            "else": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$lt": [
                            "$$h",
                            12
                        ]
                    },
                    "then": "Morning",
                    "else": {
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {
                                "$lt": [
                                    "$$h",
                                    18
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "Afternoon",
                            "else": "Evening"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to figure out any way to convert this shell operation to Java driver version. I tried MongoDB java driver docs and even Google but unable to find any way for it.

Any help on what could be the JAVA implementation for the same.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: It's all just contructed from BasicDBObject or in fact anything that is a `Map` or `List` interface for general "hash" and "array" as appropriate. Still to hard?

Comment: Did you consider to just retrieve the date as-is and then do the conversion in Java? Would likely be a lot prettier.

Comment: @Philipp The purpose is to "group" by the result. Which comes from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26748424/2313887) which is acutally a very poor and contrived example of using `$let`. It is actually not much different to just use `{ "$hour": "$Date" }` in place of the `$$h` variable provided by the `$let` operation. Don't really want to compound poor advice or otherwise re-state using `BasicDBObject` notation for the 1000th time. Be my guest if you wish to do so.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have changed it from `$let` to `$cond` and used `{"$hour":"$Date"}` in place of `$$h` using `BasicDBList`implemented it in mongo-java driver, thank you!!